# JPA query returns duplicate objects

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, join

I have this relationship in db. In the Item table the primary keys are Item_id and site. ItemPart table's primary keys are also them and there are other 2 primary keys as well. These tables are join by item_id and site as one to many relationships.

[image]

These are the 2 entity classes.

```
public class Item {

@Id
@Column(name = "item_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String itemId;
@Id
@Column(name = "site", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String site;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
private List<ItemPart> itemPart;
...

public class ItemPart {
@Id
@Column(name = "item_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String itemId;
@Id
@Column(name = "site", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String site;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "site", referencedColumnName = "site", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private Item item;
...
```

What I want is when giving an item_id return a result like below. If I give item_id = "100" and there is one item with item_id = 100 and 2 itemParts with item_id =100 and site=S01.

```
{
 "Item":[
    {
       "item_id":"100",
       "site":"S01",
       "itemPart":[
         {
            "item_id":"100",
            "site":"S01",
            "another_pk": "x"
         },
         {  
            "item_id":"100",
            "site":"S01",
            "another_pk": "y"
         }
        ],
        ... 
    }
 ]
```

But actually, it returns 2 similar item objects with each of them 2 itemPart objects. Like this.

```
{
  item:
    itemPart:[
       {...},
       {...}          
    ]
},
  {
  item:
    itemPart:[
       {...},
       {...}          
    ]
}
```

I want to fix this and I'm using JPA. Can anyone find where is the problem here.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Item p JOIN fetch p.ItemPart n WHERE 
p.item_id = ?1 ")
List<Item> findAllByItemId(String itemId);
```

Comment: what happens if you use the following query: `"SELECT p FROM Item p WHERE p.item_id = ?1"`? or if you delete @Query and use the method query `List<Item> findByItemId(String itemId);`?

Comment: It will work fine. But it generates 2 queries inside and doesn't perform join operation. I want to perform join operation that's why I used @Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put 'distinct' in the @Query then the problem was solved.

```
@Query("SELECT distinct p FROM Item p JOIN fetch p.ItemPart n WHERE 
p.item_id = ?1 ") 
List<Item> findAllByItemId(String itemId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your query like this:

```java
@QueryHints(value = {
   @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
})
@Query("select distinct p from Item p join fetch p.itemPart where p.itemId = :itemId ")
List<Item> findAllByItemId(@Param("itemId") String itemId);
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-distinct-entity-query) of hibernate documentation.